# HTML/CSS panel not displaying through JavaScript in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am trying to make it so, when the user clicks on the contact button at the bottom of the page, PHP script will check if the message was sent properly and show a panel based on the status. I've implemented a CSS class to display a panel but this is not working.

**Sample:**

The script can be found on AdamGinther.com

http://jsfiddle.net/gintherthegreat/ZFkmt/

```
<div id="contactme">
<p>Whether you’re just stopping to say hi or you have an inquiry, I enjoy receiving messages. For all of those employers out there, I am searching far and wide for a summer internship.</p>
<br> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/whoisthecoolestpersonalive?ref=tn_tnmn">
<img src="images/facebook-512.png" height="50" width="50" alt="Facebook" target="_new">
</a>
```

```
<br>
<br>
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <label name="firstName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label name="email">E-mail Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label name="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Say Hello!" id="contactbutton">
</form>
<div id="panel">
        <h1 id="output-inside"></h1>

    <br>
    <input type="button" alt="close" value="close" id="close-panel">
</div>
<?php $field_firstName=$ _POST[ 'firstName']; $field_email=$ _POST[ 'email']; $field_message=$ _POST[ 'message']; $mail_to='gintherthegreat@gmail.com' ; $subject='AdamGinther.com message from ' .$field_firstName; $body_message='From: ' .$field_firstName. "\n"; $body_message .='E-mail: ' .$field_email. "\n"; $body_message .='Message: ' .$field_message; $headers='From: ' .$field_email. "\r\n"; $headers .='Reply-To: ' .$field_email. "\r\n"; $mail_status=m ail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers); if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('#panel').show();
    $('#output-inside').text('Thank you ' + firstName + ', I will get back to you as soon as I can.');
</script>
<?php } else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('#panel').show();
    $('#output-inside').text('I am sorry ' + firstName + ', but there was a problem processing your request. I can be contacted by e-mail at GintherTheGreat@Gmail.com');
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Paste your code here or create a jsfiddle

Comment: I have checked your site, i think you need to paste your php code as well for better understanding

Comment: So I take it that you are trying to do an in page popup rather than them end up leaving this page for one generated by your PHP? If that's the case, your form should not have an action. Instead you should be using AJAX to send the form data and show the panel in the success callback. Take a look at this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

try change action page:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
```

to itself:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

because that's what you did.

However, you are trying to display popup message according to `mail();` function return. It's better if you use Ajax.

a tutorial: [Send email using Ajax](http://teachingyou.net/php/simple-php-contact-form-using-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Trying using Jquery live for events in your case

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().` http://api.jquery.com/on/